# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if' when inside function, but no error when not in a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-function

I am running into an issue with a statement in my function, however, when I don't use it in a function it works perfectly fine and I have no idea why...Here is the statement in question..

```
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
if (@PreAQ = 0)
begin
    select * from [MyTable]
        where ParentSysID = @ParentSysID
        and (
        CodeID like 'AD -%'
        or CodeID like 'CP -%' 
        or CodeID like 'DB%' 
        or CodeID like 'MC%' 
        or CodeID like 'SD -%' 
        or CodeID like 'VA%' 
        or CodeID like 'WD -%'
        )                   
end
```

I have multiple if statements, identical with that that applies more filters.

Here is the full error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure WT_FN_GET_MyTable_By_ParentSysID, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.

and I am using SQL Server 2008R2

Comment: @KenWhite, you are right. I made an edit to show the full error and which version I am using. The line error is 'if(@PreAQ = 0)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have flow control logic (`if` statement) in an [inline (single-statement)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function. Take a look at how to declare [multi-statement function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead.